# Time-evolution operator written through a commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

I found this expression for the time-evolution operator:

$$\begin{split} U(t) & = T_{\leftarrow}\exp\left[-i\int_0^t ds H(s)\right] \\ &= \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t ds\int_0^t ds' [H(s),H(s')]\theta(s-s')\right]\exp\left[-i\int_0^t ds H(s)\right]\end{split}$$

with $H$ Hamiltonian and $\theta(s-s')$ the Heaviside step function.
The commutator of the Hamiltonian at two different times is a c-number function, I don't know if it's important.

Does anyone know how to get the last part?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Please also give proper references to sources - author, title, publication - wherever possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578978/2451